# hovering svg icon over input is interrupted

Tags: jquery, css, dom, button, jquery-hover

I have the following html construction:

```
<span>
  <label>
    <input this is my button's area  />
    <span> this is the svg icon</span>
  </label>
</span>
```

I have a jQuery hover event affecting my input and the span is absolutely positioned within the input area, so it is visually above it.

The hover event changes the input class so I can change the button color, but when the mouse moves over the span that contains the icon, the hover class in the input, switches off, predictably, and the button appears not to be active.

Is there a way in which I can make the hover event to persist, eventhough I hover the sibling span without rearranging the DOM?

Comment: Try attaching the `hover` event to the label which encases both the input and span

Comment: can't do that because these elements are created dynamically. that was my first idea, but in the current development, i cannot affect anything but the inner input and span. thank you for your suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

what eneded up working for me, was incluiding a new sibling div, absolutely positioned on top of the input. just that, hover works great and, best of all, click events were not affected.

thank you all for helping me brainstorm.

**UPDATE**: still having some problems: the hover, in IE, only works when mouse is over the button's border (!!). when you hover over the absolutely positioned div or the input, the hover event is cancelled. any ideas, please? I cannot find a logical explanation.

(remember to open this link in IE to replicate issue and in chrome/ff to view the expected behaviour.)

```
$('.xtraBlock ').mouseover(function(){
    $('.popup').hover();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mrpJ/10/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are dynamically created then the only option you have would be event delegation.

`hover` cannot be delegated .  But you can attach `mouseenter`  and `mouseleave` which can be delegated

Try this

```
$('#btn-create').on('click', function () {
    $('#container').append($('#spanTemplate').clone().attr('id', ''));
});

$('#container').on('mouseenter', 'label', function (e) {
    $('input', e.currentTarget).addClass('a');
}).on('mouseout', 'label', function (e) {
    $('input', e.currentTarget).removeClass('a');
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/pQLhy/1/)**